# C - Trying to create minesweeper game

Tags: c

I am trying to practice my coding skills and recreate the minesweeper game in visual studio 2022. I am having trouble coding how many mines are touching a square within my grid. It keeps coming up with random numbers instead of how many mine it is touching. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction of where I am currently going wrong.

[image: Error which i am getting]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 10
#define MINES 10

int grid[ROWS][COLUMNS];
int revealed[ROWS][COLUMNS];



void init()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
            revealed[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
void placeMines()
{
    int i, x, y;
    for (i = 0; i < MINES; i++)
    {
        x = rand() % ROWS;
        y = rand() % COLUMNS;
        if (grid[x][y] == -1)
        {
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            grid[x][y] = -1;
        }
    }
}
void countAdjacentMines()
{
    int i, j, count;
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            if (grid[i][j] == -1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            count = 0;
            if (i > 0 && j > 0 && grid[i - 1][j - 1] == -1) count++;
            if (i > 0 && grid[i - 1][j] == -1) count++;
            if (i > 0 && j < COLUMNS - 1 && grid[i - 1][j + 1] == -1) count++;
            if (j < COLUMNS - 1 && grid[i][j + 1] == -1) count++;
            if (i < ROWS - 1 && j < COLUMNS - 1 && grid[i + 1][j + 1] == -1) count++;
            if (i < ROWS - 1 && grid[i + 1][j] == -1) count++;
            if (i < ROWS - 1 && j > 0 && grid[i + 1][j - 1] == -1) count++;
            if (j > 0 && grid[i][j - 1] == -1) count++;
            grid[i][j] = count;
        }
    }
}
void printGrid()
{
    int i, j;
    printf("  ");
    for (i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            if (revealed[i][j])
            {
                if (grid[i][j] == -1)
                {
                    printf("* ");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%d");
                }
            
        
   
                
            }
            else
            {
                printf("X ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main()
{
    int x, y;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    init();
    placeMines();
    countAdjacentMines();
    while (1)
    {
        printGrid();
        printf("Enter the coordinates of the cell to reveal (x y): ");
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        if (x < 0 || x >= ROWS || y < 0 || y >= COLUMNS)
        {
            printf("Invalid coordinates!\n");
        }
        else if (revealed[x][y])
        {
            printf("Cell already revealed!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            revealed[x][y] = 1;
            if (grid[x][y] == -1)
            {
                printf("You hit a mine! Game over.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I would find a fixed seed that causes the issue then step through the code in the debugger to see what's going on. You could also just use fixed values that cause the issue instead of random ones.

Comment: Turn up the warning level of the compiler and pay attention to them. https://godbolt.org/z/cM74fvjb9 The `printf` on line 89 is a definite bug that could manifest as a random looking value.

Comment: Side note: ```main``` should return a ```int```

Comment: `printf("%d");`  clearly a typo and not a useful question to stand on SO - voting to close.  Perhaps inspect your own code before posting and learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the print grid function, `%d` requires a value, in this case i suppose it is

```c
printf("%d ",grid[i][j]);
```

judging by the rest of the code.

Also I recommend learning how to use `gdb` for these purposes, placing breakpoints and seeing how the code evolves, or even using the `gcc` flag `-Wall`, to find some minor errors that can cause these such anomalies.